# Oracle SQL Dump file extracting parts to sql/another dump file

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-export-dump

I have a Oracle DB dump file and now I only need parts of the tables that are included there. Does anyone know how I can extract this parts into a separate dump file (or SQL)?

I thought about using the import statement. Import from dump file (full export) to dumpfile (needed parts) something like this, but don't know if its possible this way

```
import user/pw directory=fullexport_dump dumpfile=part.dmp logfile=import.log status=30
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not possible. You can only limit rows while exporting using `query` parameter.

```
exp .....  query="where id=10"
```

You may search further in the [Oracle Documentation.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch01.htm#1005545)

So, import the whole table, and create a new table with only required parts:

```
create table NEEDEDPARTS as select * from FULLEXPORT where id=10
```

Or, import the whole table and re-export with `query` parameter.